# android sqlite constraint failed on update

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an android app with a sqlite database. Sometimes when I update my table I get following error:

```
error code 19: constraint failed android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: error code 19: constraint failed
```

I don't see which constraint can fail since I have no foreign keys and I'm not inserting a NULL value.

The table:

```
    "CREATE TABLE HIST (" +
    "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + 
    "CL TEXT UNIQUE, " +
    "ACOUNT INTEGER DEFAULT 0, " + 
    "HS INTEGER DEFAULT 0," + 
    "EX INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
    "LU INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," + 
    "LT REAL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
```

The update code:

```
    SQLiteStatement updateTempStatement = db.compileStatement("UPDATE HIST " +
            " SET LT=? WHERE _id=?");

    Cursor c = null;

    c = db.rawQuery(QUERY_SQL, new String[] { hs?"1":"0" });

    Info[] result = null; 

    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        result = new Info[c.getCount()];

        int i = 0;
        int idInd = c.getColumnIndex("_id");
        int cInd = c.getColumnIndex("CL");
        int hsuInd = c.getColumnIndex("HSU");
        int ltInd = c.getColumnIndex("LT");

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                result[i] = new Info(c.getString(cInd),
                        c.getFloat(hsuInd),
                        c.getFloat(ltInd));

                updateTempStatement.bindDouble(1, result[i].getLt());
                updateTempStatement.bindLong(2, c.getLong(idInd));
                updateTempStatement.execute();

                i = i + 1;
            }
            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        }
        finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

    }

    c.close();

    updateTempStatement.close();
```

The exception is on the line of `updateTempStatement.execute();` .

The only constraint I see is the `"NOT NULL"` but the method `Info.getlt()` returns a float primitive, so it can't be NULL.

Any other ideas?

Comment: you can not update your primary key.

Comment: @Dhruvisha I'm not updating my primary key. My primary key is _id and I'm updating the field LT.

Comment: check field LT . Is it real value which you are updating?

Comment: If it is the code that causes the exception (the execute of `UPDATE HIST SET LT=?` part) and you have no (after update) triggers that can cause that exception then the only possibility is that you bind `null`. If `getlt()` really returns `float` (not `Float`) then your problem is elsewhere. Add some debug output to your update code and check the stacktrace if it is really that line that causes the exception.

Comment: @zapl, what can be "elsewhere" ? It says it's a constraint violation.. I added now some logs about the actual values of the parameters and I'm trying to reproduce it.

Comment: "elsewhere" as in other code that updates / inserts or deletes data and violates a [constraint](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint) of your database. The exception you get is generated directly by sqlite ([error 19](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html)) - there is nothing "wrong" on the java side besides issuing a bad command

Comment: how can it be another code? I get the exception in this code block.

Comment: Can you post the definition of `Info`?

Comment: @Ludo, Info has one just method, getLt(), that does some calculation and returns a float.

Comment: I suspect that calculation in `getLt()`...

Answer (score 1):

1) One of important constraints of your table is primary key. This error occurs when you try to update primary key or insert duplicate primary key into your table.

2) try:

```
c.moveToFirst();
do {    
    //...
} while (c.moveToNext());
```

3) Do you pass parameters correctly to Info(...)?

4) Do you assign values correctly in Info(...)?

Comment: I'm not updating my primary key and I'm not inserting anything to the table.

Comment: can you do clear data of your app in Android and recreate HIST. Maybe it has its old structure defined in your previous app versions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, how is this a valid column?

int hsuInd = c.getColumnIndex("HSU");

Looking at your table, the column is marked HS.

Secondly, would it not be better to use the update function?

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("LT", (Double) result[i].getLt());
int result = db.update("HIST", values, "_id = " + c.getInt("_id"), null);
```

Comment: HSU is a computed column from an expression in the query. I believe that using SQLiteStatement is more efficient (no need to re-build query each time, check the source for SQLiteDatabase).

Answer (score 0):

double check that `result[i].getLt()` really never returns null

Comment: it returns a float variable (not Float), it can't be null.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `updateTempStatement.execute();` oustside the loop.

Comment: Because this execute() method takes time and also utilizes more resources. So you may not get these unwanted errors.